# I live in Canada for many years

Tags: tense

Is it grammatically correct and does it sound native when you say as the following sentence?

> I live in Canada for many years.

With this sentence, I mean I have lived in Canada for many years.

Does the both sentence mean the same thing? Can I use present simple tense instead of present perfect tense in order to imply I still live there.

Comment: are "the country" and "a small island" the same place?

Comment: @I made a mistake but they could be

Comment: It is not *natural* to say that. Your second sentence "I have lived in Canada for many years" is correct, and means that you still live in Canada.

Comment: Worth adding that "I lived in Canada for many years" also contains the meaning that I no longer live in Canada.

Comment: Je vis au Canada depuis des années. The simple present in English (**unlike French**) with action verbs is for **customary or habitual actions**.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to imply that you still live there you could also say "I have been living in Canada for several years." (Using present perfect continuous, as the action starts in the past and continues into the present.)